# Amazon Cognito: How can the signature of an Access Token be verified?

Tags: amazon-cognito

It says in the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

that the access token must be verified. How does one go about verifying the token?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, then you're in luck. 
The way I have programmed is this,

```
    // Parse the Cognito Keys and get the key by kid
    // Key is just a class that is used for parsing JSON to POJO
    Key key = this.keyService.getKeyByKeyId(JWT.decode(token).getKeyId());

    // Use Key's N and E
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(key.getN()));
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(key.getE()));

    // Create a publick key
    PublicKey publicKey = null;
    try {
        publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // Throw error
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // Throw error
    }

    // get an algorithm instance
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) publicKey, null);

    // I verify ISS field of the token to make sure it's from the Cognito source
    String iss = String.format("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s", REGION, POOL_ID);

    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
            .withIssuer(iss)
            .withClaim("token_use", "id") // make sure you're verifying id token
            .build();

    // Verify the token
    DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

    // Parse various fields
    String username = jwt.getClaim("sub").asString();
    String email = jwt.getClaim("email").asString();
    String phone = jwt.getClaim("phone_number").asString();
    String[] groups = jwt.getClaim("cognito:groups").asArray(String.class);
```

I am using this repo to verify and parsing of the tokens,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure you are importing the following,

```
    import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
    import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
    import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
    import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException;
    import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Comment: You saved my life (or more accurately the life of my monitor because I was about to put my fist through it).  Spent days trying to get this to work with AWS Coginito.